How to reverse axes when plotting a Series?
How to swap x and y axes when plotting a time Series? Either by manipulating the Series or with Series.plot(). I know it's possible for a DataFrame, by plotting its transpose.
import pandas as pd
import numpy.random as npr

def rand_data(n=5):
    return npr.choice([1,5,6,8,9], size=n)

npr.seed(0)
n = 8
index = pd.date_range('2013/01/31 09:10:12', periods=n, freq='ME')
s = pd.Series(index=index, data=rand_data(n))
s.plot()



From the PlotAccessor class documentation, you can use these arguments 'x' & 'y' but you need to convert the Series to a Pandas DataFrame. here is what I found:
pd.DataFrame(s).reset_index().plot(x= 0,y = "index")

If the map between your index and your data is not bijective, reversing the x-axis with the y-axis will produce a non-readable line plot. Consider using a scatter plot in that case.

Do you mean swapping the x and y data like this
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(s.values, s.index)
plt.show()

or inverting the data in every axis like this
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(s.index, s.values)
ax.invert_xaxis()
ax.invert_yaxis()
plt.show()

?
EDIT:
swapping x and y data without importing matplotlib backend directly:
sframe = s.to_frame().reset_index()
sframe.plot(x=sframe.columns[1], y=sframe.columns[0])


Thanks for answering both cases, I mean swapping x and y to have a vertical time axis. I was looking for a solution specific to Pandas Series.plot() function.

Gotcha. The plot member of Series doesn't offer such an option (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.plot.html), but you can transform the series to a frame and then use columns in any order. See edited answer. You can of course do everything in one line, but I opted to split the code into two lines for clarity.

Actually you can even skip to_frame() method, since reset_index() will return DataFrame, i.e. you can do it in following one line command: s.reset_index().plot(x=0, y="index")
